# How to name file when saveAsTextFile in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

When saving as a textfile in spark version 1.5.1 I use:  `rdd.saveAsTextFile('<drectory>')`.

But if I want to find the file in that direcotry, how do I name it what I want?

Currently, I think it is named `part-00000`, which must be some default.  How do I give it a name?

Comment: This is the documentation that I found: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#saveAsTextFile  Can you suggest another source?

Comment: @Hunle What version of spark are you using?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: @Hunle, You are reading deprecated documentation, however the newest doc can be found here [Spark 1.5.2's saveAsTextFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile) Note: There isn't any difference in this area between versions 1.5.1 and 1.5.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, the documentation with examples can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile). And quoting the description of the method `saveAsTextFile`:

> Save this RDD as a text file, using string representations of elements.

In the following example I save a simple RDD into a file, then I load it and print its content.

```py
samples = sc.parallelize([
    ("abonsanto@fakemail.com", "Alberto", "Bonsanto"),
    ("mbonsanto@fakemail.com", "Miguel", "Bonsanto"),
    ("stranger@fakemail.com", "Stranger", "Weirdo"),
    ("dbonsanto@fakemail.com", "Dakota", "Bonsanto")
])

print samples.collect()

samples.saveAsTextFile("folder/here.txt")
read_rdd = sc.textFile("folder/here.txt")

read_rdd.collect()
```

The output will be

```
('abonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Alberto', 'Bonsanto')
('mbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Miguel', 'Bonsanto')
('stranger@fakemail.com', 'Stranger', 'Weirdo')
('dbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Dakota', 'Bonsanto')

[u"('abonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Alberto', 'Bonsanto')",
 u"('mbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Miguel', 'Bonsanto')",
 u"('stranger@fakemail.com', 'Stranger', 'Weirdo')",
 u"('dbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Dakota', 'Bonsanto')"]
```

Let's take a look using a Unix-based terminal.

```
usr@host:~/folder/here.txt$ cat *
('abonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Alberto', 'Bonsanto')
('mbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Miguel', 'Bonsanto')
('stranger@fakemail.com', 'Stranger', 'Weirdo')
('dbonsanto@fakemail.com', 'Dakota', 'Bonsanto')
```

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer to this question is that `saveAsTextFile` does not allow you to name the actual file.

The reason for this is that the data is partitioned and within the path given as a parameter to the call to `saveAsTextFile(...)`, it will treat that as a directory and then write one file per partition.

You can call    `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('/some/path/somewhere')` and it will create `/some/path/somewhere/part-0000.txt`.

If you need more control than this, you will need to do an actual file operation on your end after you do a `rdd.collect()`.

Notice, this will pull all data into one executor so you may run into memory issues.  That's the risk you take.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to name the file as @nod said. However, it's possible to rename the file right afterward. An example using PySpark:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
    "mapred.output.committer.class",
    "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter")
URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
fs = FileSystem.get(URI("s3://{bucket_name}"), sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file_path = "s3://{bucket_name}/processed/source={source_name}/year={partition_year}/week={partition_week}/"
# remove data already stored if necessary
fs.delete(Path(file_path))

df.saveAsTextFile(file_path, compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")

# rename created file
created_file_path = fs.globStatus(Path(file_path + "part*.gz"))[0].getPath()
fs.rename(
    created_file_path,
    Path(file_path + "{desired_name}.jl.gz"))
```