# Converting spark dataframe to flatfile .csv

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe (hereafter `spark_df`) and I'd like to convert that to `.csv` format. I tried two following methods:

```
spark_df_cut.write.csv('/my_location/my_file.csv')
spark_df_cut.repartition(1).write.csv("/my_location/my_file.csv", sep=',')
```

where I get no error message for any of them and both get completed [it seems], but I cannot find *any* output `.csv` file in the target location! Any suggestion?

I'm on a cloud-based Jupyternotebook using spark '2.3.1'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving dataframe to local file system results in empty results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603404/saving-dataframe-to-local-file-system-results-in-empty-results)

Comment: seems both questions are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
spark_df_cut.write.csv('/my_location/my_file.csv') 
//will create directory named my_file.csv in your specified path and writes data in CSV format into part-* files.
```

We are *not able to control the names of files* while writing the dataframe, look for **directory** named **`my_file.csv`** in your location `(/my_location/my_file.csv)`.

In case if you want **filename ending with *.csv** then you need to [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660002/how-to-name-file-when-saveastextfile-in-spark) using **fs.rename** method.

Answer (score 0):

`spark_df_cut.write.csv` save the files as part files. there is no direct solution available in spark to save as .csv file that can be opened directly with xls or some other. but there are multiple workarounds available one such work around is to convert spark Dataframe to panda Dataframe and use `to_csv` method like below

```
df  = spark.read.csv(path='game.csv', sep=',')
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf.to_csv(path_or_buf='<path>/real.csv')
```

this will save the data as .csv file

and another approach is using open the file using hdfs command and cat that to a file.
please post if you need more help